# How can I import a .CSV with timestamps to Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2010, ms-office

I know how to import a CSV file, but my problem here is that the file contains WebKit timestamps (it's my browser history for those interested). Now when importing, I have three options for the format - General, Text, and Date. If I select General, it correctly formats the timestamps as a number, but also changes them to scientific notation (so I lose precision).

On the other hand, if I select Text, it doesn't change the timestamps but when I later convert that column to numbers, I can't filter (I get "Text filters" rather than "Number filters"). This is important because I want to show only entries from, say, this morning.

Date does the same thing as General (in case anyone asks).

The only solution I can think of is to overwrite all the timestamps in my file with Excel's date format and then import, which would be inconvenient and feels dirty. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: A sample of the timestamp data, and how it is being handled, would be useful in helping with this problem

Comment: Microsoft Excel internally stores dates as days so 1 equals 24 hours and 0.5 equals 12 hours and so on. As a date "0" would be the 1st January 1900.

WebKit Timestamps store dates as microsconds since 1st January 1601.

Comment: @RCrowt That is interesting.  What calendar does it use for the early years, (before use of the Gregorian calendar was widespread).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm not entirely sure as I have never had a need for dates so early. I would assume negative numbers but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *convert* them to scientific notation. You are seeing that because the column isn't wide enough. Excel imports all the precision possible.

Comment: It's definitely changing the numbers and increasing width doesn't help, but now I've had another look and it's not as bad as I had assumed (I'm only losing the two least significant numbers). Still losing precision but it looked a lot worse to me than it actually is.

Comment: There's a limit of around 17 significant digits in a 32-bit float. Only way around that is to import it as a text column and split the number up afterwards into separate components for (1) `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and (2) fractions of a second.

Comment: Ahh thanks, that explains it. I should've known that actually; I must punish myself now.